# Word for the love of participating in new worlds?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm searching for a word that describes being passionate about participating in and building new things in other worlds or communities. Note that this is unrelated to the exploration of those realms.

Some examples would be:

- A fascination with building a colony on Mars. (But not necessarily exploring the planet.)
- Passion for building things in Minecraft, or role playing in other virtual worlds.
- Longing to travel, not to see new places, but to experience or influence different communities, places, or cultures.

The word could be descriptive, "He loved to _______, that's why he went to Mars." a title, "He was a ________, that's why he went to Mars." or any other term that fits, usage is not a restriction.

Comment: I would be tempted to call such a person an _Edentate_ — that is, a potentate of a newly created Eden.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Worldbuilding SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Explore, adventure, travel...

Comment: How about an "alternaut", someone who likes navigating alternative worlds?

Answer (score 1):

As far as a noun (which your second blank requires), you can try

**world-builder**

> Once you step Inside the Funhouse..you will see that the world-builders are just as weird as the worlds they build.

Above example from the *Oxford English Dictionary* (OED)

Also: *world-maker* from the same source.

Also **settler**, as one who settles in a colony is helping to build it.

Comment: The hyphenated world-something is a good idea. I'm looking more for world-participator or world-lover. Any other world- ideas?

Comment: @StephenBelden -- World-building (hence the term world-builder) is an _actual thing_.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to settle for different words all of those points.

In addition to Knotell's answer of world-builder for your first and second points, there's **wanderlust** for your third.

[wanderlust: the wish to travel far away and to many different places](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/wanderlust)

- > In July wanderlust takes over the whole nation.
- > Many of our troops now abroad will be possessed of the wanderlust when they return.
- > Vikings' seaworthiness and wanderlust resulted in new areas being developed.

There's also *globetrotter*, but I don't think it fits as well as wanderlust.

[globetrotter: someone who often travels to a lot of different countries:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/globetrotter)

A **pioneer** is [one of the first to settle in a territory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pioneer), and we frequently hear about someone's *pioneering spirit*.

> Throughout history, women have evidenced a strong pioneering spirit. They have charted new paths, explored virgin territory, endured hardship, and braved danger.
>
> Perhaps the first image of a pioneer that comes to mind is of wagon
>   trains headed into the Western frontier. Those early settlers
>   demonstrated tremendous courage, risk, and inner fortitude–traits that
>   are still needed today. Harrowing stories of pioneer women abound. As
>   they forged into new territory, the trials they suffered are nearly
>   unimaginable in our convenience-based society. [[source]](http://enrichmentjournal.ag.org/200102/046_pioneer_spirit.cfm)